# android system app on disable does it provide callback

Tags: android, system, android-lifecycle

Currently I wrote a system service that runs and is able to setup a global http proxy.

However, If the user manually disables the app, is there are any sort of shutdown or service unbind call back that happens?

When a user disables a system app, does the app end immediately?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.   system broadcasts the Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED action when an app is disabled by the user.